# creating dynamic records in single form using JS and store the info in a List or set object using spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I need to create form fields like name , age and city inside a form and this should happen every time i click add record. i dont want multiple forms all dynamic group should be created within a single form. on submitting the data should be taken by controller using modelattribute, and store in arraylist or any ...help out to find it. i have used following links and almost got it but unfortunately got deleted.

https://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/
http://www.nobukimi.com/?p=237

answer 
https://netjs.blogspot.com/2018/09/spring-mvc-binding-list-of-objects-example.html

Comment: I just noticed your questipon, it may be late reply. [Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57798021/2825798)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting a spring model attribute list element using an index from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358950/getting-a-spring-model-attribute-list-element-using-an-index-from-javascript)